# Removing a git commit and erasing all records of it

Tags: git

This may have been asked before however I can't seem to find a similar question elsewhere on Stackoverflow or on the interweb. I am learning git and trying to wrap my head around the concepts.

The issue I have is how can I delete a file or directory from my working directory or tree and have its "history" deleted as well. I have not yet started pushing the files to any remote repository.

I start as follows;

1. cat > file1.txt
2. git add file1.txt
3. git commit -m "File 1 commit"
4. rm file1.txt
5. git status shows me the message Changes not staged for commit: deleted: file1.txt

**Questions**

1. What's the difference between git rm and rm? My understanding is that the former creates a deletion record in git's history
2. Does deleting the file always get recorded in git's history?
3. How do I delete the file as well as the commit history?
4. How would this be any different if I had multiple commits?
5. What issues can I run into deleting a commit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `rm` just removes a file from the file system.  If `git` was tracking it, you need `git rm` to stop it from doing so.
2. If it was tracking it, yes, deleting it will also be part of the tracked history for that file.
3. Rewrite your branch's history to not include the initial commit of the file.  In your case, that's as simple as `git rebase -i` and squashing the commit where you delete the file into the commit where you added it.
4. Yes, you'd need to squash them *all* together.  Alternately, as the rebase goes along, just fix all of the conflicts by choosing the deleted revision.
5. Lots of potential conflicts with commits that modified the file in the interim.

Comment: When you say tracking, I assume you mean that I have run the command `git add {filename}. If I have not yet committed it but have staged it, will it still be stored in history? I would have thought it would not. Can you elaborate on squash? What do you mean by `conflicts with commits that modified the file`?

Comment: 1. If you haven't commited it, there's no tracking except the index.  You can just "git rm --cached" it to get it out.  2. Squashing means editing history to combine two commits into a single commit.  3. If you added a file in commit A, and deleted it in commit C and then squashed them together, you will get a conflict with commit B if commit B contained edits to the file.

Comment: Thanks. I assume that deleting it in Commit C would only occur if I had committed a change to that file. What if I deleted the file in Commit A? Secondly why would I want to combine the commits into a single commit?

Comment: What do you mean deleted it in Commit A?  Isn't that the commit where you added it in the first place?  Combining the commit where you create the file and the commit where you delete it would effectively remove that file from the entirety of the history.  Isn't that what you're asking about?

Answer (score 0):

one of the best guides I've seen on this is from github

https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data

a more `simple` way if its your last commit  is using rebase and force pushing it

```
git rebase -i
git push origin +master
```

And your questions.

1. `rm` is a system "remove" command. Git's RM relates to gits internals. If you delete a file from your hard drive, Git will have a copy of it and will be able to recover it.
2. All changes if commited are recorded in gits history. If you make a file and then delete it without commiting to git, Git doesnt know about it and therefore not recorded
3. The link above has info on deleting a file from all commits
4. same as above
5. If someone else is using it or branches from your deleted commit, git will struggle to merge changes. There are usually few cases where you actually need to delete from git

Comment: Thanks. When would I use `git rebase -i HEAD~{number}?

Comment: when you have more than 1 commit you want to get rid out. The number is how many commits you want to combine in to 1

Comment: Sorry for being a newbie, what would I want to combine my commits?